# How rebuild sphinx RT index?

Tags: sphinx, rt

I add new field to rt index, how i can rebuild it?
If i do truncate rtindex new field do not added. I saw it from desc rtindex. Should i stop sphinx service and unlink all index files and then do reindex?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience: if you need to modify RT-index schema, you have to stop sphinx daemon, delete all index-related files by mask

> index_name*

and binary logs of sphinx. After that you could modify schema in sphinx config, start daemon and rebuild RT index (you need write script for this).